# Hosting a site error occur

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\sevabharathitvm.org\httpdocs\Gallery\zp-core/version.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\pear;./includes;./pear') in
>   D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\sevabharathitvm.org\httpdocs\Gallery\zp-core\global-definitions.php
>   on line 6

this is the error occuring when     host my site in online.when i include zenphoto  plugin in gallery section.but it canot display..means not working,

Answer (score 0):

Check that the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\sevabharathitvm.org\httpdocs\Gallery\zp-core/version.php' actually exists and has the proper file permissions.  It also may not be included in your search path, which you can update in the php.ini [per the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)